# Search form block not showing in IE7 and IE8

Tags: search

Search shows fine in chrome but not in IE8- looking at the code the DIV block-search-form simply isn't there. This occurs in different themes and also if I change where search should be displayed.

I'm on a fresh install of 7.12 with commerce kickstart, internationalization and other pretty standard modules.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the search block appear in IE9?

Comment: I'm afraid not. If the code were there I would assume it's a CSS issue. I'm just starting with Drupal so I don't know what other IE issues exist. Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that if I logout of Drupal the search disappears in Chrome as well. So it's not a browser issue. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your commments it's a permission issue. To solve it select People -> Permissions from the admin menu (or use the path admin/people/permissions) then look for Search and give 'Use search' (and possibly 'Use advanced search') permissions to the roles you want.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot. I'm new to using a CMS so I'm still not thinking of permissions when in comes to troubleshooting. Must. change. mindset. ;-)